# Handlebars Partial Undefined Could Not be Found

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I need to dynamically render partial with certain names. In the back end, I set the following:

**render.js**

```
 const myPartialFunction = _.constant('site/myPartial');
```

And in the hbs template, I try to get the value of `myPartialFunction`

**page.hbs**

```
{{> (myPartialFunction)}}
```

It renders the partial correctly, but I got the following error:

```
The partial undefined could not be found
```

However the following doesn't cause error

**page2.hbs**

```
  {{> site/myPartial}}
```

Though using `{{> (myPartialFunction)}}` works, getting error every time the page is rendered is very annoying
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Would you happen to have a hash in your URL when loading the page? I'm running into the "partial could not be found" issue as a result.